# Datatables - Search; but do not instantly filter the data table

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have been starting to use datatables.net jQuery library and its searching method. However, I currently I have the following problem:

I would like to use the search functionality but I do not want to have the automatically filtering available. In other words, when I search for a term, I would like to keep all the data in the table. By default, the search functions as a filter (instant-search). This means on key-up the data table shrinks when the term has not been matched and only the rows are displayed that contain the term. This is not what I need. Has anybody experienced this problem before and has a solution for it?

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything on the datatables.net website.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok . What do you want to do then? You aren't telling us what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to delay the filtering of the rows? Or Something?

Comment: Please see the comment under @markpsmith post. Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-10-22) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said how you want the search to perform, so I'll assume it's on the Return key press.

First you need to unbind the default 'keyup' event from the search input:

```
$("div.dataTables_filter input").unbind();
```

Then bind a new event which checks that the return key has been pressed, then perform the search:

```
$("div.dataTables_filter input").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            oTable.fnFilter(this.value);
        }
    });
```

Where `oTable` is your `datatable` object

You haven't said which version of `Datatables` you're using, this is v1.9 syntax. To change it to v1.10 you need to use `oTable.search(this.value)`

Comment: Sorry, my goal is to have a search which just highlights the searched term in the table. At the moment (by default), the search functions like a filter since the table is minimised by the searched term. All data that are not equal to the search term are not displayed. However, I would like to keep the entire table. So when the return key is pressed, the searched term is highlighted in the table but the table still has all values. I hope this makes it more clear?!