# DataTables - kill ajax requests when a new one has started

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using DataTables 1.10.15 in Server Side mode.

I'm passing the contents of a form to a PHP script via ajax in order for it to search a database:

```
 var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
    "processing": false,
    "serverSide": true,
    "searching": false,
    "ajax": { 
        "url" : "/getData.php",
        "data" : function ( d ) {
            // Search input data
            d.field1 = $('#field1').val(),
            d.field2 = $('#field2').val(),
            d.field3 = $('#field3').val()
        },
        "method" : "POST",
    }
 });
```

I have some other js which checks for at least 3 characters entered into a field before firing the ajax request to `/getData.php`.

This means - after 3 characters have been entered - that an ajax request is made *each time* a key is pressed, so there can be a queue of ajax requests.

```
$('#primarySearch input[type="text"]').on({
    "keyup": function(e) {
      // Ignore tab key.
      if (e.which != 9) {
        processPrimarySearch.call(this);

      }
    }
});


/* Handle Primary Search */
function processPrimarySearch() {
    var obj = $(this),
        search_id = obj.attr('id'), // e.g. #field1
        search_value = obj.val(); // e.g. '123-456'

    /* Wait until at least 3 characters have been entered, or user has cleared the input */
    if (search_value.length >= 3 || (!search_value) ) {
        myTable.draw();
    }   
}
```

How can I kill off the previous ajax requests whenever a new one is made, so that they don't queue in this way? I've read [How can I stop all the currently ongoing Ajax queries that DataTables instance have started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531937/how-can-i-stop-all-the-currently-ongoing-ajax-queries-that-datatables-instance-h) but the solution is for an older version of DataTables and the accepted answer doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: You cannot. It is already processing on the serverscript.

Comment: I understand that the server is processing the script getData.php. But it is possible to stop ajax requests (e.g. `.abort()` in jquery). So what I'm trying to do is if, say 2 requests, have been made to `getData.php`, it kills the first one and then moves on to the next. Such that there is no queueing of scripts. The application works on each keypress so if the user enters 4 characters for their search it doesn't need to do the first 3 searches - they can be killed off before the server processes them. I know it's possible because it's on the link I posted, just for an old datatables version.

Comment: You could set a flag, like `processing`, and then avoid to execute the ajax-request if `processing` is true, Upon ajax success, set `processing` to false.

Comment: You could also insert a delay for executing the search. Hijack the search input events and fire the search only after an interval of 500 ms. This has been asked and answered several times before.  I know there is an answer if you google a little bit.

Comment: Ok thank you. I think the bit about the flag is perhaps what I was missing and seems like a good idea.

Comment: This happens because the default behaviour of the datatables search field is to do a lookup after each keypress, obviously this isn't ideal for server-side data.  You can change this behaviour so that the search isn't performed until you press 'enter'. [stackoverflow.com/questions/39464462/datatables-search-but-do-not-instantly-filter-the-data-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464462/datatables-search-but-do-not-instantly-filter-the-data-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using the search field that DataTable offers by default, you'd want to use the [`searchDelay` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchDelay). By default it is set to 400ms when you use server-side processing. However, you have `"searching": false`, therefore you cannot use this option for your use-case.

You provide your own custom `input` element to perform searches. This is a perfectly valid use of DataTables. **However, what you should do is not abort requests after they are created but prevent the creation of extraneous requests in the first place.** What you should do is debounce your calls to `myTable.draw()` In the example below I'm using Lodash's [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce). You could use an implementation from another library if you want. In the following example, I've also modified the event handling to check whether the input field value has actually changed between keystrokes. You were checking for tabs but that's only the tip of the iceberg. Using arrow keys will also generate `keyup` events. Event just pressing and releasing the shift key will generate a `keyup`. The code below takes care of all those situations by checking whether the value of the field has changed since the last stroke and just ignore the event if there has been no change.

I type fast enough that if I type "I'm a little teapot" in the field presented in the example below I'm seeing "drawing" on the console only once.

```js
// We create a new function that will debounce calls to the draw() function.
var debouncedDraw = _.debounce(function() {
  // myTable.draw();
  console.log("drawing");
}, 500);


var prev_value = undefined;

/* Handle Primary Search */
function processPrimarySearch() {
  var obj = $(this),
    search_id = obj.attr('id'), // e.g. #field1
    search_value = obj.val(); // e.g. '123-456'

  // There's been no change to the field, ignore.
  if (prev_value === search_value) {
    return;
  }
  prev_value = search_value;

  /* Wait until at least 3 characters have been entered, or user has cleared the input */
  if (search_value.length >= 3 || (!search_value)) {
    debouncedDraw();
  }
}

$('#primarySearch input[type="text"]').on("keyup", processPrimarySearch);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="primarySearch">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

---

You asked in a comment if you should keep the code you had that aborts any previous Ajax query launched by DataTables when DataTables launches a new query. I would remove it. I've never relied on such code ever in my applications. (You mentioned [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531937/how-can-i-stop-all-the-currently-ongoing-ajax-queries-that-datatables-instance-h). Yes, I do use the code in the answer I gave there but that's tear down code which is part of a test suite, not application code.) In theory it would seem like it is a good thing to do. After all, a new query makes the old ones obsolete so why not ditch the old queries and save some work? Right? In practice, the gains would be modest because:

1. At the speed humans interact with your GUI, chances are that by the time an `abort()` call is issued, the Ajax request will already have been sent out on the network. (I actually ran some manual tests, and indeed, I was never fast enough to prevent the browser from sending the request out.) So it means that the server will receive it even if you abort it.
2. Furthermore, `abort()` is not meant to notify the server that the request has been cancelled. So you won't save work on the part of your server. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery) for the issues. (Searching for "server" on the page will bring you right where people talk about the issue of whether the server is notified, and what to do if you need to notify the server that a request has been cancelled.)

You may be saving some redrawing time but that's not something I'd worry about until it is actually a problem.

On the other hand, aborting requests like this *may cause other problems.* For the sake of seeing what would happen, I modified one of my applications to abort old requests, and the whole thing immediately bombed. Aborting requests did not play well with the way I've set up `DataTables`. I don't know what exactly is causing the problem. Maybe I'm using just the right settings to get it to go boom. Or I'm using a plugin that does not like aborted requests. At any rate, aborting requests can cause problems.

Comment: Excellent. There are many things I hadn't considered - never even heard of debounced functions before. Will look into this a lot more. Many thanks.

Comment: can you also confirm if I can remove some code I added to stop ajax requests queueing which was `if (settings.jqXHR) settings.jqXHR.abort();` - this was placed inside `.on( 'preXhr.dt', function (e, settings, data)`

Comment: My thoughts ran too long for a comment so I've edited my answer.